# want to replace .php?url= this part by / from my url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

In my website there is a link like this 
http://backlinks.cheapratedomain.com/backlinks.php?url=emobileload.com

for better SEO I want to make it like this 
http://backlinks.cheapratedomain.com/backlinks/emobileload.com

just want to replace '.php?url=' by '/'

My question is how can i do this by editing my .htaccess file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only for that one URL, then you could try this:

```php
RewriteRule ^backlinks/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]*)$ backlinks.php?url=$1 [L]
```

So requested URLs like `http://backlinks.cheapratedomain.com/backlinks/domain.com` will be redirected to `http://backlinks.cheapratedomain.com/backlinks.php?url=domain.com`

Comment: Hi cod you give it work but page did not find my css file. How can i solv it ?

Comment: Where is your css file? Is it in the same folder?